# Add project to GIT source control

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, version-control

I'm learning to use `GIT` as primary VCS for my projects. I added solution, did some work, everything was fine. But then I added one more project to solution, and it broke. It seems that project is excluded from source control and this is why I cannot push any changes. I removed another old project, added one new, but cannot push changes - old project is still alive when new project is stored locally. When I open github app I see that changes are here, but I cannot check-in them.

[image]

You see that `XLinq` project is pushed as expected, but `XLinqTest` doesn't have lock image so it's excluded from source control.

When I'm trying to check-in from shell it says that everything is fine:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ZAT [master +1 ~1 -0 !]> git push -u origin --all
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

How can I add fit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing `git status` and check if the files you want to send appear on the `Untracked files:` section.

if they do, you can execute `git add XLinqTest\file1 XLinqTest\file2 ... etc` and that's it (you may also try with `git add XLinqTest\*`).

if they don't appear on the `Untracked files:` section then your `.gitignore` file contains a rule that excludes them.
find the rule and you should be good to go.
(note: I recommend using www.gitignore.io to create your .gitignore rules)

you can now do another `git status` and you should see the files appear on the `Changes to be committed:` section.

you can then perform a `git commit -m 'added files for some reason'`.

after this you should see:

```
[master (root-commit) xxxxxx] added
 N files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 fileA
 create mode 100644 fileB
 ...
 create mode 100644 fileN
```

and if you do `git status`:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

you can do `git push` to push the changes to your remote repo/branch.

after that you may want to do this quick git course https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 .

cheers!

Comment: They was untracked for some reason. Thanks for an answer and course link!